# How to define shared library path for a compiled Go program during compilation

Tags: go, shared-libraries

With the introduction of `-linkshared` one can write a go program that uses shared libraries and end up with much smaller compiled files.

By default the final executable file looks for the shared libraries under `GOROOT` path.

What I am trying to achieve is to have all our libraries installed under our own custom directory (say /usr/local/ourprogram/lib) and then having our executable to look there for the libraries.

One solution is to have a simple shell script alongside our executable and  assign the `GOLANG` environment variable and then call our program. Somethine like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GOROOT=/usr/local/ourprogram/lib; ourprogram
```

But what I wish to achieve is to have that path somehow inside our program in order to avoid having that extra bash script.

Is this achievable through a compilation flag or maybe a comment directive?

Comment: how about LD_LIBRARY_PATH, for this is linux shared library standard.

Comment: Hi Jiang, Can you please elaborate? What I want to do is to install all our GO libraries on a predefined directory on all our enusers and for go to dynamically look there and link them rather than always looking for them under  /usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_amd64_dynlink/

Comment: `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable. The in-executable name is called the `rpath`, is defined at link time, and requires that the shared modules have the `soname` set properly. On OS X, the shared library must have `@rpath` in its `install_name`. On Windows, DLLs are automatically searched in a specific search order and I don't know if you can tell it to look in specific folders. I do not know how to actually do any of this with `-linkshared`; sorry.

Comment: @Reza env LD_LIBRARY_PATH:=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:YOUR_SO_PATH ourprogram

Comment: That is almost the same as what I am doing with GOROOT env variable. What I want to do is to provide that value during compile time (what we can do with C) and only for go libraries. So I am not asking about linking to a shared c library but Go packages that are build as shared.